# Initiating a renegotiation in PyOpenSSL

Tags: python, openssl, pyopenssl

I need to perform a renegotiation on an open connection in python. It seems that [the `renegotiate` function is not implemented](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/blob/master/OpenSSL/SSL.py#L1431). Is there any way I can initiate a renegotiation?

I have tried setting the connection to a connect state using `set_connect_state()` and then calling `do_handshake`, but this causes a cipher block padding error when consumed by the other end of the connection.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to implement the renegotiation function myself. I included OpenSSL's renegotiate function in the Cryptography binding [#2303](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/pull/2303) and added this into the renegotiate function in PyOpenSSL [#305](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/pull/305), but this pull request is pending the next release of Cryptography.